# Remote desktop software which dedicates identical but separate desktops to clients

Tags: remote-access, desktop-client, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a software that works like a remote desktop but the person who is sitting in front of the monitor doesn't see the changes. i'm currently working with [Real VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/) but that does not support this particular feature.

the software should allow access to server (host) computer from both internal and external networks, just like what Real VNC does. for example in Real VNC multiple people can connect to a host computer but they all share the same desktop and their actions are visible on the Host monitor and using [Bitvise SSH](http://www.bitvise.com/) i can share files without any notice but that doesn't support desktop sharing.

the computer that provides access to multiple clients has a 5th gen core i7 CPU with 16GB of RAM, so not even close to a server config and thus please consider the limitations for suggestions. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I've found what i need, it is [X2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/start) **but only for Linux**.

Comment: I guess what i need is somehow similar to the result of the answer of this question, but in a legal way. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56181/hack-into-a-computer-through-mac-and-ip-address

Comment: "the person who is sitting in front of the monitor doesn't see the changes", but, per your comment, you want to do it "in a legal way", so I guess you just want him to be able to get on with his work while you get on with yours. Presumably, then, it would be acceptable for him to have to give permission at the beginning of the session?

Comment: Yes. that's right. i don't want someone to need to give permission or grant administration access for the remote software because there might be some times that no one is sitting behind the computer.

Comment: what operating systems do your need to remote from and to?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 8.1 X64